# Canvas don't support symbols in node js

Tags: javascript, canvas, symbols, discord.js

I'm trying to use canvas now for my Discord Bot. But canvas don't support symbols(๑ ; ₪ ; ۩ ; ≡ ; for exemple). When someone use the command the bot crash without any error...

```js
        if (message.content === prefix + "idcard") {

          let sender = message.author

          console.log(`\n[COMMAND] &idcard by ${sender.tag} [` + new Date() + `]`);

          const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            let fontSize = 40;

            do {
              ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px Janda Manatee Solid`;
            } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);

            return ctx.font;
          };
            const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 350);
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
            const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            ctx.font = applyText(canvas, "๑₪۩≡ Mina Mina Sama ≡۩₪๑");
            ctx.fillStyle = '#585858'; 
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.fillText("๑₪۩≡ Mina Mina Sama ≡۩₪๑", 420, 75);
            //normally it's "sender.username" but for exemple we will use this username
            const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), `${sender.username}'s-idcard.png`);
        
            message.channel.send(attachment);
    
        }
```

[When we use the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AP1x.png)

And I tried to use Arial font and sans-serif font. Same error...

Comment: If you don't have a font with these chars measureText would return 0 and your while loop crash your script. So crash is easily avoided (check width before the loop) but I don't know how to set up fonts on your setup.

Comment: I tried to check the width before the loop but same thing. When I do the measureText the bot crash immediatly.

Comment: Then your canvas lib is broken. You may want to open an issue on their bug-tracker. Also, you may want to check what is produced by a simple ctx.fillText